# Is it mandatory to use trialforce for all ISV apps?

Tags: trial, trialforce

Is it mandatory to use all trialforce for all apps? I just want to keep on pushing the latest package to appexchange. I am seeing that publishing console does not show the latest package. I would prefer not to use a trailforce if we can avoid that.

Comment: Is this brand new package, or new version? How long did you wait?

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to use trail-force for Appexchange packaging. You can use Developer edition org and register it with your partner username, you would be able to publish the package to Appexchange.

However Salesforce always recommend to use trialforce to keep packaging consistent.

Package not appearing:-

- A new upload to existing package doesn't take time to reflect in publishing console. Check with your packaging configuration the it is uploaded correctly.